# Can we get location of Whatsapp media folder in iOS like in Android : Whatsapp/Media/WhatsApp Images ? iPhone

Tags: ios, whatsapp

Can we get location of Whatsapp media folder in iOS like in Android  : Whatsapp/Media/WhatsApp Images

Can we fetch all images programmatically in iOS?

(or) is there anyway to detect media is from WhatsApp?

Comment: All iOS apps are sandboxed

Comment: How do you make it on Android?

Answer (score -1):

you should backup iOS data to Mac computer, and you can find it in /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/xxx, first xxx is your computer name, and second is your ios'UUID, in manifest.db of that directory you can find location of Whatsapp media, but it is complex a lot， you should have some sql acknowledge.

Comment: Though it is not directly related comment to the original question but its worth mentioning that there are few applications which make this complex task easy. I wrote once from another project for myself https://github.com/borun/WhatsApp-Elixir